# Cordova AngularJS routing doesn't work on device but works on ripple

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, cordova, device, ngroute

It's been two days that I'm trying to understand why but I didn't find a solution to my problem.
I developed various small simple applications using Apache Cordova with Visual Studio and AngularJS.
I have a problem with routing. The application works perfectly on the RIPPLE emulator but not on my device! It shows nothing and it does not display any errors!

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Constent-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <title>handsi</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="appmain">

    <div id="app-content" ng-view></div>

    <a href="#contacts">show contacts</a>

    <!--Scripts-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/platformOverrides.js">         </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/frameworks/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/frameworks/jquery/jquery.mobile.1.4.5.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/frameworks/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/frameworks/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/routes/app_routes.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/frameworks/materialize/materialize.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/handsi_tools.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/directives/menu.js"></script>
    <!--/scripts-->
</body>
</html>
```

index.js :

```
(function () {
"use strict";
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);

var app = angular.module('appmain', ['ngRoute']);

function onDeviceReady() {
    // Gérer les événements de suspension et de reprise Cordova
    document.addEventListener('pause', onPause.bind(this), false);
    document.addEventListener('resume', onResume.bind(this), false);

    // TODO: Cordova a été chargé. Effectuez l'initialisation qui nécessite Cordova ici.

    //Initialisation
    $(".button-collapse").sideNav({
        menuWidth: $(window).width() < 400 ? 300 : 370,
        closeOnClick: true
    });
};

function onPause() {
    // TODO: cette application a été suspendue. Enregistrez l'état de l'application ici.
};

function onResume() {
    // TODO: cette application a été réactivée. Restaurez l'état de l'application ici.
};})();
```

angular-route.js :

```
(function () {
angular.module('appmain', ['ngRoute']).config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $compileProvider) {
    $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file|tel):/);
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $routeProvider
        .when('/login', {
            template: '<p>Say hello world ! Welcome to login screen</p>',
            controller: function () {
            }
        })
        .when('/contacts', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/contacts/contact.html'
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/login' });
});

angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('app-content'), ['appmain']);
})();
```

I have a problem with routes, please do you have any idea how to resolve my problem ?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is you ui frame work ?

Comment: I use Materialize for ui.

Comment: I find solution after a lotf search, the problem is
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);